# A power series expansion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex, series-expansion

Consider the function,  $f(z) = z\, \tanh(\pi z) \log (z^2 + a^2)$ for some $a>0$.

Now I am considering 3 different situations,

- $z = i(n+0.5) - i\epsilon + \delta - it$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and we integrate from $t=0$ to $t=1-2\epsilon$.
- $z = i(n-0.5) + i\epsilon - \delta + it$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and we integrate from $t=0$ to $t=1-2\epsilon$.
- $z = i(n+0.5) - i\epsilon - \delta - it$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and we integrate from $t=1-2\epsilon$ to $t=0$.

Now in any of these cases I am truncating the Taylor expansion of $f$ (and the integration limits) to zeroth order in $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ and then doing the integration. (...because that is the limit that interests me.)

I am using the `Series` function of *Mathematica* twice (once each for the two infinitesimals) to get this zeroth order term and I get that,

- For the first and third cases this zeroth order term comes out to be, $\frac{1 + 2(n-t)}{2}\cot [\pi (n-t)]\log[a^2 - (\frac{1 + 2(n-t)}{2})^2]$
- In the second case this zeroth order term comes out to be, $\frac{-1 + 2(n+t)}{2}\cot[\pi (n+t)]\log [a^2 - (\frac{-1 + 2(n+t)}{2})^2]$

Now the confusion is this - hence symbolically for the first and the third cases the integrations are negative of each other (as I would expect!) but the second case turns out to be distinctly different. But if you think on the z-plane then the second and the third are exactly the same paths on which the integration is being done.

Then why this difference?

---

In the comments confusions were raised about how the series was done - so here is the code for the first case,

```
z = I (n + (1/2) - x - t) + y; 

Assuming[  
  n ∈ Integers && n < a && a > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && t > 0,  
  Series[z Tanh[π z] Log[z^2 + a^2], {y, 0, 2}]]
```

Doing the above produced the zeroth order term in "y" ($\delta$) to be,

> ```
> -(1/2) (1 + 2 n - 2 t - 2 x) 
>     Log[a^2 - 1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 t - 2 x)^2] Tan[1/2 (π + 2 n π - 2 π t - 2 π x)]
> ```

So then I did an "x" ($\epsilon$) series on it,

```
Assuming[  
  n ∈ Integers && n < a && a > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && t > 0   ,  
  Series[
    -(1/2) (1 + 2 n - 2 t - 2 x) 
      Log[a^2 - 1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 t - 2 x)^2] Tan[1/2 (π + 2 n π - 2 π t - 2 π x)], 
    {x, 0, 2}]] 
 // FullSimplify
```

This produced the expression, $\frac{1 + 2(n-t)}{2}\cot[\pi (n-t)]\log [a^2 - (\frac{1 + 2(n-t) }{2})^2]$ as the zeroth order term.

Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: @Artes "i" is the usual imaginary unit $\sqrt{-1}$. $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are real numbers. There is nothing much of a Mathematica code here - all I have done is a series expansion in $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ of $f(z)$ in the 3 cases and I have written down what the respective answers are.

Comment: @Artes I am not sure what you are referring to! I got those exprepressions by doing the "Series" command on my $f$. Thats it and thats all. I want to understand why option 2 and 3 are giving so different answers when they are exactly the same things.

Comment: @Artes Its your choice if you would want to help - in my question I have now reported the "Series" command that I used - in case this is what was bothering you.